# setting timeout in await promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following code:

```
ig = await login({
            inputLogin: username,
            inputPassword: 'thisispassword',
            silentMode: true,
            //inputProxy: 'http://' + randomProxy,
            inputProxy: false,
            onlineMode: false,

        });
```

however in the event of bad connections and some sort of disconnects, login will just hang in there.. so i wanted to have some timeout for this login thing, so I changed it to use Promise.race ... however after modifying the code to this

```
ig = await Promise.race([login({
            inputLogin: username,
            inputPassword: 'thisispassword',
            silentMode: true,
            //inputProxy: 'http://' + randomProxy,
            inputProxy: false,
            onlineMode: false,

        }), pause(10000)]);
```

it complaints that it can't find pause .. what am I doing wrong here ? i basically want to set the login to timeout for 10 seconds if callback is not returning anything within that timeframe

Comment: Why do you think it should be able to find `pause`? I don't see you defining it in the code you provided.

Comment: Why not define a timeout on request level?

Comment: Adjust the `login` method to specify a timeout. Here's the docs for how to do it on the raw `XMLHttpRequest`, but most libraries allow you to set a timeout too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pause` isn't a standard JavaScript global function, nor a standard Node.js global function.

If you want a function that waits a given number of milliseconds before fulfilling a promise, you have to write it:

```
function pause(ms, value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));
}
```

But adjusting the logic of `login` so it applies a timeout instead seems like a better approach, if that's an option.